# What’s com.apple.iomfb_bics_daemon in macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, startup, launch-services

I noticed in my boot logs that this service fails to start because the executable is missing. So, what is it supposed to do? I can’t find much about it on the internet besides that it was introduced in macOS Monterey and also exists on iOS.

What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the it does is help manage the IOMobileFrameBuffer (sending pixels to the screen) and since that’s internal to the OS and a shared system on multiple operating systems - parts of the code aren’t relevant on different systems (intel vs Apple silicon and macOS vs iOS vs iPadOS), there’s not been any public documentation this part of the code afaik.

That subsystem became famous when people figured out how to run unentitled app code on iOS that escaped the security expected by sandboxing + entitlements for a third party app and let unexpected code run at the kernel level. (Causing crashes or worse - privacy and/or security breaches)

- https://saaramar.github.io/IOMFB_integer_overflow_poc/

What specifically did the error say? Sometimes [errors are harmless or even expected behavior](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253062488).

Comment: It just said that it can’t find the service to launch, so it tried to launch it but just couldn’t find it. Doesn’t seem to cause issues on my system but I’m just curious what it does and why it’s trying to load it but fails